# How to center a popup-div below the mouse cursor but keep it completely inside the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to display a popup-div below the mouse cursor, but it should be completely inside the visible area. Display the div below the mouse cursor worked:

```
var popupHeight = $("#popup").height();
var popupWidth = $("#popup").width();
$("#popup").css({
    "position" : "absolute",
    "top" : lastClickPosition.pageY - (popupHeight/2),
    "left" : lastClickPosition.pageX - (popupWidth/2))
});
```

The problem with this simple approach is that the popup-div may be partly outside the screen. So I tried to calculate the minimal and maximal offsets for it to stay within the screen:

```
Math.min(Math.max(0, lastClickPosition.pageY - (popupHeight/2)), 
         windowHeight - popupHeight - 20)+"px"
```

But this approach fails after the page was scrolled down because pageX/Y is relative to the page and not visible part.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add in the `scrollTop` of the `window`. See [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$(window).scrollTop(); // this is the scroll distance from the top
```

> The vertical scroll position is the
>   same as the number of pixels that are
>   hidden from view above the scrollable
>   area. If the scroll bar is at the very
>   top, or if the element is not
>   scrollable, this number will be 0.